# AudioClip no sound - Java

Tags: java, audio

I am trying to play a .wav sound but I can't hear it. There are no errors.

```
public void SoundClipTest() {
    try {
        File file = new File("");
        File soundFile = new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + "/coin.wav");
        AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioIn);
        clip.start();
    } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have tried different **.wav** files. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("");
            File soundFile = new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + "/coin.wav");
            AudioInputStream audioIn = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audioIn);
            clip.start();
            Thread.sleep(60 * 1000); // The sleep time should be length of your wav file
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok I have sound, but I don't want to loop it.

Comment: clip has its own thread, to keep clip's thread alive, just sleep the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it in Applet Programming, then you can use the following.

```
/* AppletAudioPlay.java */
/* Applet playing a sound */
public class AppletAudioPlay extends Applet
{
AudioClip a;
String msg,msg1;
public void init()    
{
    a=getAudioClip(getCodeBase(),"audio.wav");
}
public void start()
{
    a.loop();
}
public void stop()
{
    a.stop();
}
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.drawString("Audio System Now Playing....",10,30);
    showStatus("Playing a song");
}    
}   

/*   
<html>    
<applet code=AppletAudioPlay.class width=400 height=400>
</applet>
</html>
*/
```

Comment: I am not using it in applet